# Problem with getting OpenCV image data to C#

Tags: c++, opencv, dll

So I'm fairly new to C++, and I tried to use it to read images using the OpenCV library. My idea was to put the C++ code in a DLL and then get the decoded image by calling the DLL from a C# script (I need the image in C#).

I looked arround a bit on what would be the best way to send the bytes to C#, and saw that most people were using a `char*` to store bytes. That could then be returned by a C++ function and stored as a C# `string` like so:

```
char* GetSomeBytes()
{
    // Got this method of allocating memory from the internet, sadly can't remember from were
    // (I get memory errors if I pass my_bytes directly)

    size_t stSize = strlen(my_bytes) + sizeof(char);
    char* pszReturn = NULL;

    pszReturn = (char*)::CoTaskMemAlloc(stSize);
    strcpy_s(pszReturn, stSize, my_bytes);
    return pszReturn;
}
```

and then in C#:

```
[DllImport(path_to_my_dll, EntryPoint = "GetSomeBytes", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern string GetSomeBytes();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string raw_bytes = GetSomeBytes();

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(raw);
}
```

And this even worked, but now I had to get the raw data from the `Mat` to a `char*`. I was quite sure I had to use the `Mat.data` field, but that contained a `unsinged char*`. There were several ways in which I tried this conversion:

- Using a simple cast (like `(char*)my_mat.data`)
- Using reinterpret_cast (like `reinterpret_cast<char*>(my_mat.data)`), which some people said would be better for C++
- Using memcpy like:

```
int size = my_mat.total() * my_mat.elemSize();
char* bytes = new char[size];
memcpy(bytes, my_mat.data, size);
```

So here's my problem: When I used `my_mat.total() * my_mat.elemSize()` on a full-hd image, it returned `6220804`, what makes sense to me (because `1920 * 1080 = 2073600`, so the image has 2.073.600 pixels, and `2073600 * 3 = 6220804`, the image has 3 color channels, and so it takes a total of 6.220.804 bytes to store it).

However, after the conversion to a `char*`, with every one of the three methods above, `strlen(the_converted_bytes)` was something completely different with every image I tried, ranging from about 2.000 all the way up to about 11.000.000. `bytes.Length` in C# returned the same value though, so I don't think the error is in the C++-char* to C#-bytes process. I tried different charsets in both the `DllImport` and the `Encoding.GetBytes` anyway, but that didn't seem to help.

So I think there is something wrong with my understanding of `char` and `unsigned char` or with pointers. Or both. Anyway, it really seems to me that it should be possible to convert the data of a C++ `Mat` to a C# `byte[]`. Isn't it possible to convert between a `unsinged char*` and a `char*` as easily as I thought, or have I overlooked something completely different (maybe there's something wrong with my use of `my_mat.data`)?

I would apreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, nevermind, turns out it actually makes more sense to just return the `unsigned char*` from the C++ function and then convert it in C#. If anyone else has problems with this, [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/f3fe6378-3d80-4040-a752-6a9dd17a1f5e/unmanaged-unsigned-char-array-to-managed-byte-array)'s the thread I found this answer on (Thanks to [Louis.fr](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/louis.fr/?ws=usercard-mini)).

Here are the methods I ended up using:

In C++:

```
unsigned char* GetUnsignedBytes(char* image, int* bytes_count)
{
    Mat img = imread(image);

    int size = img.total() * img.elemSize();
    unsigned char* raw_bytes = new unsigned char[size];

    memcpy(raw_bytes, img.data, size * sizeof(std::byte));
    
    *bytes_count = size;
    return raw_bytes;
}
```

and in C# (`using System` and `using System.Runtime.InteropServices`):

```
[DllImport(path_to_my_dll)]
public static extern IntPtr GetUnsignedBytes(string image, out int bytes_count);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IntPtr ptr = GetUnsignedBytes(some_image, out int bytes_count);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[bytes_count];
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, bytes_count);
}
```

Glad it was this simple after all. [Louis.fr](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/louis.fr/?ws=usercard-mini) also wrote that you could just pass a pointer, but as far as I understand using these pointers in C# would require unsave code (compiling with `/unsave` or something like that). So I think I'm going to stick with this method, as long as I don't stumble into further problems with it in the future.